# Вычисление определителя второго порядка, можно ли на JS без AJAX?

Tags: javascript

Можно ли без использования AJAX в данном коде более элегантно вытянуть значения из input? Я пробовала через $(input).eq(index), не работает. Ведь если будет матрица больше, то получится много костылей...

```js
function getResult() {
  var a11, a12, a21, a22;
  a11 = document.getElementById("1").value;
  a12 = document.getElementById("2").value;
  a21 = document.getElementById("3").value;
  a22 = document.getElementById("4").value;
  document.getElementById("result").value = a11 * a22 - a12 * a21;
}

function resetAll() {
  document.getElementById("result").value = 0;
}
```

```html
<h1>ВЫЧИСЛЕНИЕ ОПРЕДЕЛИТЕЛЯ 2 ПОРЯДКА</h1>
<input type="text" id="1" value="" size="5" placeholder="0">
<input type="text" id="2" value="" size="5" placeholder="0">
<br>
<br>
<input type="text" id="3" value="" size="5" placeholder="0">
<input type="text" id="4" value="" size="5" placeholder="0">
<hr>
<input type="button" onclick="getResult()" value="Вычислить">
<input type="button" onclick="resetAll()" value="Сбросить">
<hr>
<label for="result">Результат</label><input type="text" value="0" id="result">
```

Comment: getElementsByClassName не подойдет?

Comment: AJAX тут совершенно не причём. Вы случайно его с jquery не перепутали?

Comment: getElementsByClassName я не думаю, что подойдет, ведь если будут разные классы, то это по сути те же айдишники. Правильно же?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman нет, не перепутала) если подскажете решение с применением jQuery, то буду благодарна

Comment: @Наталья просто я не понимаю как вам тут может помочь ajax. Классы и идентификаторы - это разные вещи. Но в вашем случае можно дать input имена и обращаться по ним.

Comment: ajax - это технология асинхронного запроса к серваку

Comment: Обычно работа с данными в форме идет либо через, так скажем, стандартную отправку запроса на сервер (с применением серверного ЯП), либо при помощи ajax... хотелось бы без этого всего обойтись, вот к чему вопрос.

Comment: @Наталья А зачем вам отправлять данные на сервер? Детерминант можно без всякого сервера посчитать, на клиенте

Comment: @Darth я это и хочу сделать. Ваш вариант намного лучше получился, спасибо)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
 // С помощью этой функции вы можете получить матрицу любого размера 
 // в виде двумерного массива.
function getMatrix(){
  const matrix = [...document.getElementsByClassName('matrix')].reduce((res,el) => {
    const [x,y] = el.id.split('_');
    if(!res[x]) {
      res[x] = [];
    }
    res[x][y] = el.value;
    return res;
  }, []);
  return matrix;
}

function getResult() {
  const matrix = getMatrix();
  document.getElementById("result").value = matrix[0][0]*matrix[1][1]-matrix[0][1]*matrix[1][0];
}

function resetAll() {
  document.getElementById("result").value = 0;
}
```

```html
<h1>ВЫЧИСЛЕНИЕ ОПРЕДЕЛИТЕЛЯ 2 ПОРЯДКА</h1>
<input type="text" id="0_0" value="" size="5" placeholder="0" class='matrix' >
<input type="text" id="1_0" value="" size="5" placeholder="0" class='matrix' >
<br>
<br>
<input type="text" id="0_1" value="" size="5" placeholder="0" class='matrix' >
<input type="text" id="1_1" value="" size="5" placeholder="0" class='matrix' >
<hr>
<input type="button" onclick="getResult()" value="Вычислить">
<input type="button" onclick="resetAll()" value="Сбросить">
<hr>
<label for="result">Результат</label><input type="text" value="0" id="result">
```